# Problems with JQuery's Droppable Tolerance 'fit' feature when using the same size divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, droppable

I'm just wondering if anybody else can manage to get the tolerance:'fit' option to work when using the 'droppable' feature in jQuery's UI?

I want to call a function only when the draggable div is dropped perfectly onto a droppable div. Both divs are the same size and I'm using snapMode:outer to help the end user.

I simply cannot get it to work with 'fit'. Works perfectly with 'intersect'.

Would really appreciate some help.

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over the same problem and it seems that for the time being you need to patch jquery-ui to make it work.

The patch is extremely simple and obvious and is described in the following jquery-ui bug report: http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/5689

I have no idea if this is really a bug or a "feature", though.

Comment: Hey David – thanks for this.

It drove me mad. As a workaround, I ended up nesting the 'snapping' div inside the droppable div, making the droppable div 1px bigger to the top, right, bottom and left.

Answer (score 0):

For those using the jQuery UI module in Drupal 6, you can fix it manually:

- Go to /sites/all/modules/jquery_ui/jquery.ui/ui/minified
- Find the file "ui.droppable.min.js" and make a backup of it (just in case something goes wrong).
- Open the original ui.droppable.min.js and search for the text "fit" (with the quotes).
- Change the line that says

> return(F< D&&C< B&&N< L&&K< J); (spaces on purpose, not in the original line)

to

> return(F<=D&&C<=B&&N<=L&&K<=J);

and save the changes.
 - Done, enjoy.